# Selects que afectan a otros selects con jquery

Tags: php, jquery, select

Tengo 5 selects en cascada con la jerarquia siguiente: Ley, Titulo, Capitulo, Sección y Subsección. He conseguido que al seleccionar una ley, se muestren los titulos a los que pertenecen esa ley, si después selecciono un titulo, este afecta al select de capitulos y me muestra a los capitulos que pertenecen a ese titulo ... y así sucesivamente. Este es el codigo jquery que utilizo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nuevotitulo").hide();
    
        $("#sel_ley").change(function(){
            var leyid = $(this).val();
            
            //Fin mostrar/ocultar

            $.ajax({
                url: 'gets/gettitulos.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {select_ley:leyid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                    var len = response.length;
                    $("#sel_titulo").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id_tit = response[i]['id_tit'];
                        var num_tit = response[i]['num_tit'];
                        var nombre_tit = response[i]['nombre_tit'];

                        $("#sel_titulo").append("<option value='"+id_tit+"'> TITULO "+num_tit+"&nbsp;"+nombre_tit+"</option>");
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
    
    <!-- Script Titulo a Capitulos-->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nuevocapitulo").hide();
        
        $("#sel_titulo").change(function(){
            var tituloid = $(this).val();
            
            //Ocultamos o mostramos boton nuevocapitulo
            //Fin mostrar/ocultar

            $.ajax({
                url: 'gets/getcapitulos.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {select_titulo:tituloid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;
                    $("#nuevocapitulo").show(); 
                    
                    $("#sel_capitulo").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id_cap = response[i]['id_cap'];
                        var num_cap = response[i]['num_cap'];
                        var nombre_cap = response[i]['nombre_cap'];

                        $("#sel_capitulo").append("<option value='"+id_cap+"'> Capitulo "+num_cap+"&nbsp;"+nombre_cap+"</option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
    <!-- Script Capitulos a Secciones-->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sel_capitulo").change(function(){
            var capituloid = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'gets/getsecciones.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {select_capitulo:capituloid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $("#sel_seccion").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id_sec = response[i]['id_sec'];
                        var num_sec = response[i]['num_sec'];
                        var nombre_sec = response[i]['nombre_sec'];

                        $("#sel_seccion").append("<option value='"+id_sec+"'> Seccion "+num_sec+"&nbsp;"+nombre_sec+"</option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
    
    <!-- Script secciones a SubSecciones-->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sel_seccion").change(function(){
            var seccionid = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'gets/getsubsecciones.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {select_seccion:seccionid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $("#sel_subseccion").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id_sub = response[i]['id_sub'];
                        var num_sub = response[i]['num_sub'];
                        var nombre_sub = response[i]['nombre_sub'];

                        $("#sel_subseccion").append("<option value='"+id_sub+"'> Seccion "+num_sub+"&nbsp;"+nombre_sub+"</option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Tengo 2 problemas (entiendo que relacionados):
El primero es que solo consigo que el select afecte al select jerarquico inferior con lo que si después de seleccionar una ley, luego un titulo, y luego un capitulo, si vuelvo a seleccionar una ley, solo se "refresca" el titulo y sigue mostrando los datos de capitulos que no pertenecen a esa ley.
El segundo, si en mi base de datos, el primer titulo de una ley tiene capitulos o secciones o subsecciones, al hacer select en una ley, me muestra el primer titulo pero no los capitulos o secciones o subsecciones que pueden depender de él. (solo afecta a un select).

Haciendo pruebas no he conseguido  que un select afecte a más de uno... a ver si me podeis ayudar. Si necesitais mas info no dudeis en pedirme..
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos.**

Debes colocar un llamado en cascada de esos AJAX al momento que cambia el dato; así como tener bien definido cuando solo limpiar y también poblar los `select`; a grandes rasgos y sin entrar tanto en detalle sería algo como lo siguiente (respecto al código que compartes):

> Observo usas `jQuery`. Por simplicidad no abordare los momentos que ocultas, muestras u otra acción en tu interfaz/componentes.

```
var aplicarCascada = true; // Nuestro flag

$(function () {
   // Asociar el change a cada select
   $("#sel_ley").change(function () {
      aplicarCascada  = false;
      // Primero limpias; para asegurar quitar elementos previamente existentes
      $("#sel_titulo").empty();
      $("#sel_capitulo").empty();
      $("#sel_seccion").empty();
      $("#sel_subseccion").empty();

      var idActual = $(this).val(); // Tu valor actual seleccionado

      $.ajax({
         //Tus opciones
         success : function () {
            var len = response.length;

            // Haces tu foreach

            aplicarCascada  = true;
            $("#sel_titulo").change(); // Invocamos el siguiente elemento

         }
      });
   });

   $("#sel_titulo").change(function () {
      if (aplicarCascada) {
         aplicarCascada  = false;
         // Primero limpias; para asegurar quitar elementos previamente existentes
         $("#sel_capitulo").empty();
         $("#sel_seccion").empty();
         $("#sel_subseccion").empty();

         var idActual = $(this).val(); // Tu valor actual seleccionado

         $.ajax({
            //Tus opciones
            success : function () {
               var len = response.length;

               // Haces tu foreach

               aplicarCascada  = true;
               $("#sel_capitulo").change(); // Invocamos el siguiente elemento

            }
         });
      }
   });

   $("#sel_capitulo").change(function () {
      if (aplicarCascada) {
         aplicarCascada  = false;
         // Primero limpias; para asegurar quitar elementos previamente existentes
         $("#sel_seccion").empty();
         $("#sel_subseccion").empty();

         var idActual = $(this).val(); // Tu valor actual seleccionado

         $.ajax({
            //Tus opciones
            success : function () {
               var len = response.length;

               // Haces tu foreach

               aplicarCascada  = true;
               $("#sel_seccion").change(); // Invocamos el siguiente elemento

            }
         });
      }
   });

   $("#sel_seccion").change(function () {
      if (aplicarCascada) {
         aplicarCascada  = false;
         // Primero limpias; para asegurar quitar elementos previamente existentes
         $("#sel_subseccion").empty();

         var idActual = $(this).val(); // Tu valor actual seleccionado

         $.ajax({
            //Tus opciones
            success : function () {
               var len = response.length;

               // Haces tu foreach

               aplicarCascada  = true;

            }
         });
      }
   });
})
```

> También incluir `aplicarCascada  = true` aún cuando la petición `ajax` devuelva error.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Perfecto!!! Muchas gracias RobertoLeOr. Después de revisar y modificar algunas cosas, la funcionado correctamente.